# Reinstalled OS without decrypting my drive

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-11, bitlocker, decryption

Processor:Ryzen 9 3900x
Motherboard: Aorus x570 elite

A while ago I encrypted my E:\ drive which had most of my stuff and forgot about it. I had to reinstall windows (C:) due to some issues and forgot to decrypt the drive before doing that. Important thing to note is that I had not enabled AMD fTPM untill then.

I upgraded my BIOS, enabled  AMD fTPM and installed Windows 11. I don't know if these series of sequences had any affect on the accessibility of the BITLOCKER encrypted drive but I want to give out as much information as possible.

Now I reinstalled my Windows 11 after meeting the Microsoft eligibility criteria, and now BITLOCKER won't even recognize my drive as encrypted so there is no place to key-in the recovery key and no way to unlock my drive.

I checked bde-status for all drives, it shows E as unencrypted.

Does anyone have a way around this?

No information about the drive is accessible at all not even the size.

[image]

Comment: There's no way around it. You should have backups in any situation but particularly when using any form of encryption.

Comment: Even if I have a recovery key for my previous desktop from my Microsoft account?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that key was for your previous desktop's system volume (C:\), not for a data volume.

Comment: add disk management screenshot pls.

Comment: The error in the screenshot indicates a permissions problem not necessarily a problem with BItLocker, although, BitLocker might complicate the entire situation. You shouldn't have had to worry about your BitLocker data protected volume.  I suspect something else is going on outside of the fact it was encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data on disk E, I would suggest to rollback to
Windows 10 and undo all the BIOS changes you have done.
You only have 10 days for doing this since the day that you
upgraded to Windows 11.

A clean reboot might then have a chance to recognize your disk
(but this cannot be guaranteed).

If your problem is Bitlocker, there is no way to access the data without
using the Bitlocker software to unlock it, so you need to return to
a state where Bitlocker recognizes and can unlock the disk.